# What is this operation in numpy called?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I've been going over the numpy docs looking for a specific operation. The words I would use for this are "overlay" or "mask" but the numpy concepts of those words don't seem to match mine.

I want to take two arrays, one dense and one sparse and combine them thusly:

> ```
>   [ 1, 2,  3, 4,  5 ] 
> X [ N, N, 10, N, 12 ] 
> = [ 1, 2, 10, 4, 12 ]
> ```

where X is the operation and N is None, or Null, -1, or some other special character.

How is this achieved in numpy/python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
# pick special value 
N = -1

dns = [ 1, 2,  3, 4,  5 ] 
sprs = [ N, N, 10, N, 12 ] 

# this is important otherwise the comparison below
# is not done element by element
sprs = np.array(sprs)

# tada!    
np.where(sprs==N,dns,sprs)
# array([ 1,  2, 10,  4, 12])
```

When called with three arguments `m,a,b` `where` "mixes" `a` and `b` taking elements from `a` where `m` is `True` and from `b` where it is `False`.

Comment: Both you and @Willem have given me insights I needed. I'm marking Paul's answer as the one since he needs the points. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can "fill" the masked array, with [**`np.ma.filled(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.filled.html), for example:

```
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> b
masked_array(data=[--, --, 10, --, 12],
             mask=[ True,  True, False,  True, False],
       fill_value=999999)
>>> b.filled(a)
array([ 1,  2, 10,  4, 12])
>>> np.ma.filled(b, a)
array([ 1,  2, 10,  4, 12])
```

Here we thus fill the masked values from `b` with the corresponding values of `a`.